# Not able to upload Binary Images Using Core Service2011 API from Java Client?

Tags: 2011, core-service, java

I am trying to upload binary images through the Java Client using Core Service API.
I am facing an issue while uploading the binary content using the `IStreamUpload.uploadBinaryByteArray()` method. While invoking this method, I am getting the following exception:

> The message with Action 'http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011/IStreamUpload/UploadBinaryByteArray' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).`

Can you please suggest what needs to be added to the below code to make it work?

```
public void createBinaryComponent(String title, String folderUri,
        String schemaUri, ICoreService client, IStreamUpload streamUpload)
        throws Exception {
    // folder uri tcm:62-12340-2
    // title PWRFTPXL
    // schemaUril tcm:62-1523-8

    ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
    ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions();
    ComponentData newComponent = (ComponentData) client.getDefaultData(
            ItemType.COMPONENT, "tcm:62-13493-2");
    LinkToSchemaData schema = objectFactory.createLinkToSchemaData();
    schema.setIdRef("tcm:62-1509-8");
    newComponent.setSchema(schema);
    newComponent.setComponentType(ComponentType.MULTIMEDIA);
    newComponent.setTitle("PWRTESTGIF");
    String customMetadata = "<Metadata xmlns=\"http://www.metlife.com/Schemas/Asset\"><AssetMeta><Title>pwrasset</Title><LongDescription>pwr</LongDescription></AssetMeta></Metadata>";
    newComponent.setMetadata(customMetadata);

    LinkToApprovalStatusData approvalStatus = new LinkToApprovalStatusData();
    approvalStatus.setIdRef("tcm:0-0-0");
    approvalStatus.setTitle("Undefined");
    newComponent.setApprovalStatus(approvalStatus);

    // UploadResponse us = new UploadResponse();
    // D:\\13.4 release\\Power Reviews\\Test\\badge_vp_fr_CA.gif
    // C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Lighthouse.jpg
    File file = new File(
            "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Lighthouse.jpg");
    file.setReadable(true);
    file.setExecutable(true);
    // FileInputStream fileinputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    // byte[] result = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    //      
    byte[] bytearr = read("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Lighthouse.jpg");

    String tempLoc = streamUpload.uploadBinaryByteArray(file.getName(),
            bytearr);
    BinaryContentData binaryData = new BinaryContentData();
    // binaryData.setBinaryId(value);
    binaryData.setFilename(file.getName());
    newComponent.setIsBasedOnTridionWebSchema(true);
    binaryData.setIsExternal(false);
    // binaryData.setMimeType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

    LinkToMultimediaTypeData multimeidatype = objectFactory
            .createLinkToMultimediaTypeData();
    multimeidatype.setIdRef("tcm:0-2-65544");
    multimeidatype.setTitle("Jpeg image");
    binaryData.setMultimediaType(multimeidatype);

    binaryData.setUploadFromFile(tempLoc);
    // newComponent.setId("tcm:0-0-0");
    newComponent.setBinaryContent(binaryData);
    client.create(newComponent, null);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Check out the sample code below. You will of course have to change all the references to TCM URIs to meaningful values on your system. Also, I'm uploading a file called `Beagle.jpg` which initially exists in the `C:\` folder of my client machine.

```
ICoreService client = CoreServiceFactory.getBasicHttpClient();

ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions();
ComponentData componentData = (ComponentData) client.getDefaultData(ItemType.COMPONENT, "tcm:1-1-2", readOptions);
componentData.setTitle("MMC " + System.currentTimeMillis());

LinkToSchemaData linkToSchema = new LinkToSchemaData();
linkToSchema.setIdRef("tcm:1-26-8");
componentData.setSchema(linkToSchema);

File localFile = new File("C:\\Beagle.jpg");
File remoteFile = uploadFile(localFile);
BinaryContentData binaryContentData = new BinaryContentData();
binaryContentData.setFilename(localFile.getName());
binaryContentData.setUploadFromFile(remoteFile.getAbsolutePath());

LinkToMultimediaTypeData linkToMultimediaType = new LinkToMultimediaTypeData();
linkToMultimediaType.setIdRef("tcm:0-2-65544");
binaryContentData.setMultimediaType(linkToMultimediaType);
componentData.setBinaryContent(binaryContentData);

componentData = (ComponentData) client.save(componentData, readOptions);
client.checkIn(componentData.getId(), true, null, readOptions);
```

And the uploadFile method is like this:

```
private File uploadFile(File file) {
    try {
        byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        dis.readFully(fileData);
        dis.close();
        IStreamUpload clientUpload = CoreServiceFactory.getStreamUploadBasicHttpClientClient();
        String uploadFile = clientUpload.uploadBinaryByteArray(file.getName(), fileData);
        return new File(uploadFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

More info about the `CoreServiceFactory` class and this version of Java Core Service client is available on my blog http://yatb.mitza.net and http://yatb.mitza.net/search?q=Core+Service+Java

Comment: Hi Mihai, Thanku so much for the reply...Actually the issue for me is i am not able to upload the file into content manager.It is faling when i am accessing the String uploadFile = clientUpload.uploadBinaryByteArray(file.getName(), fileData);

Comment: Getting the following error: The message with Action 'http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011/IStreamUpload/UploadBinaryByteArray' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Comment: I am using the same core-service-client-2011sp1hr1.jar provided in your blog. I am facing issue to access streamDownload_basicHttp end point methods.Please suggest is there anything else we need to add to access the streamDownload_basicHttp end point.I am able to access the basicHttp end point and create simple components.

Comment: I have not used the streamDownload endpoint, but only the streamUpload to push the binary to the server. All worked out of the box for me. For binaries larger than 16K, I had to increase the reader quota, as explained in my blog post http://yatb.mitza.net/2013/05/create-multimedia-component-using-core.html

Comment: i am really Sorry ...it was my typo mistake...i am using the same Stream Upload end point and the code as given by you. I am using the same CoreServiceFactory and the Test class from your blog only. I am using the same uploadFromFile() method  private static File

Comment: uploadFile(File file) {
        try {
            byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            dis.readFully(fileData);
            dis.close();
            IStreamUpload clientUpload =
                    CoreServiceFactory.getStreamUploadBasicHttpClientClient();
            String uploadFile = clientUpload.uploadBinaryByteArray(file.getName(), fileData);
            return new File(uploadFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: I getting the IStreamUpload stub instance bujt while trying to access String uploadFile = clientUpload.uploadBinaryByteArray(file.getName(), fileData);

Comment: I am getting the The message with Action 'sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011/IStreamUpload/…; cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Comment: Hi Mihai...Can you please share your Tridion web.config StreamUpload binding settings.i feel the security/binding settings are incorrect in our case.

Answer (score 2):

Per my knowledge, the issue should be because of the difference in the byte[] in .NET and Java.

As far as I know, byte[] in java stores data in Big Endian format, whereas byte[] in .NET stores data in Little Endian.

May be you can try converting your byte[] representation in Java client in Little Endian, and then try calling the `IStreamUpload.uploadBinaryByteArray()` method with this updated byte[].

See, the cause is obvious from the error message, whatever string and byte[] parameter in JAVA you are sending from java client, the .NET WCF service is not treated that as same string and byte[] array in .NET.